# Loop in render view

Tags: ajax, grails, view

Guys I need to call an action that performs a loop to render a template several times. I also need that the element that contains the template be updated. How Can I do that. I've already tried, but the template doesn't appears and the element that contains the template isn't updated. Below, my code. Thanks.

```
def myAction(){

    def i = 0;
    while(i<5){
        i++;
        render template:"console", model:[dado:dado]
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than try and render the entire template multiple times could you break out the section that needs repeating and wrap that in `<g:each>` within a gsp then render the section as a template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is unclear, but if you need to repeat the template several times on a view try this code:

```
def myAction(){
   //instantiating dado
   [dado: dado]
}
```

The view (suppose it should be placed to `/controllerName/myAction.gsp`):

```
<g:each in="${(0..4)}">
     <g:render template="console" model="${[dado: dado]}"/>
</g:each>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ajax, you can pass the data with html tag.

```
def myAction(){
        render template:"console", model:[dado:dado]
}
```

Now in view,

```
$.ajax({
url:<controller/action>,
data:data,
success:function(data){
for(var i =0; i<5;i++)
    $(slectedDiv).html(data);
}
}
});
```